# Node.js / Express app not returning the correct EJS page

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am building a website using Node.js, Express and EJS. For now I have two EJS templates, each corresponding to a page on the website:
the home page URL should be `/` or `/home`. The "staff" URL should be `/staff`. The home one works fine, but for some reason even when I visit the `/staff` or even a nonsense address (e.g., `/eduwshduhwudhwud`) I still get the home page. Here is my code that's inside the `app.js` which is used to build the routes.

**Here is my folder structure and code:**
[image: directory structure]

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();


app.use(express.static("public")); // To allow static files
app.set("view engine", "ejs"); 

// -------------------------------- HOME PAGE-----------------------------------

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("home");
}); 

app.get("/home", function(req, res){
    res.render("home");
})
// -------------------------------- STAFF PAGE-----------------------------------

app.get("/staff", function(req, res){
    res.render("staff");
}); 

// -------------------------------- HOME PAGE-----------------------------------

// -------------------------------- HOME PAGE-----------------------------------

// -------------------------------- HOME PAGE-----------------------------------

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("SERVER IS RUNNING!");
})
```

Comment: What happens if you move `app.use(express.static("public"));` to below your other `.use()` definitions?  I have a feeling your static is eating your other routes.

Comment: Just tried and it is still doing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Use `path.join(__dirname, 'views')` to combine the application's directory (i.e., [_dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname)) to your views directory.

This is how I am doing it in my application:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
...
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); // <-- add this line before your view engine definition
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
...
```

Given this, within my routes I can refer to any view in the views folder with `res.render()`. For example:

```
res.render('dashboard', { title: 'My App', greeting: 'Hello' });
```